# accessing double pointer to structure

Tags: c, structure

I am trying to frame a data packet using the following structure pointer

```
typedef struct address {
    unsigned char *mac_destn_addr;
    unsigned char *mac_src_addrl
}address_t;

typedef struct frame {
    address_t     *eth_addr;
    unsigned char *payload;
    unsigned int  *crc32;
}frame_t;

typedef struct eth_ctrl {
    unsigned char *no_of_pkt;
    unsigned short *delay;
    frame_t     **eth_frame;
}eth_ctrl_t;

address_t *adr;
frame_t *frame;
eth_ctrl_t *control;

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    adr = malloc(sizeof(address_t));
    frame = malloc(sizeof(frame_t));
    control = malloc(sizeof(eth_ctrl_t));

    frame->eth_addr = adr;
    control->eth_frame = &frame;

    printf("CRC32 : 0x%x\n", (*control)->eth_frame->crc32);
}
```

it prints the address of `crc32` variable. I need to print the value which is present at that address.
i tried with `*(*control)->eth_frame->crc32`, `**(control->eth_frame->crc32)` it doesn't prints the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

`->` expects the LHS to be a pointer, so anything starting with `(*control)->` is guaranteed to do something weird since `control` is only a single pointer.

I think you want:

```
*(*control->eth_frame)->crc_32
```

or possibly just

```
*control->eth_frame[0]->crc_32
```

In other words:

`control` is an `eth_crtl_t*`

`control->eth_frame` is a `frame_t**`

`*control->eth_frame` is a `frame_t*`

`(*control->eth_frame)->crc_32` is a `unsigned int*`

`*(*control->eth_frame)->crc_32` is an `unsigned int`

`control` is a pointer. Dereference it, and take the element called `eth_frame`. That is a double pointer. Dereference it, dereference it again, and take the element called `crc_32`. That is a single pointer. Dereference it only once.